# How to query a SQL Server table in C# which results only in one single row?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to query a SQL Server table like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE REC_ID = 1
```

I know that this query can only return one single record by design. Normally I would do:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    ct = new ctyp();
    ct.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MyID"]);
    ct.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
  }
}
```

But in this case I have always need to use the `reader.Read()` method although I know that the returned count of records is only one.

Is there any other to handle queries or do a execute... which results in one object?

Comment: Do you mean "*this query can only return one single* ***row***"?

Comment: You say *"i have always need to use the reader.read() method although i know that the returned count of recordsets is only one."* as if this is hugely cumbersome, it is neither costly in terms of performance or hard work to write, I would just stick with using `while (reader.Read())`. For what it is worth though, the `reader.HasRows` check is redundant since you will never enter the loop `while (reader.Read())` if it doesn't.

Comment: No, there's no shortcut - you still need to call `reader.Read()` to actually get to the first row in the reader, and then you can grab the data you're interested in from the reader. The only "shortcut" is if your query returns just a **single row, single column** (like a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM.....`) - then you can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to get that one returned value. Or you could use an **ORM** like Entity Framework and get rid of all this boring, error-prone glue code altogether!

Comment: @RBarryYount: Yes i meant "one single ROW"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SQL statement is expected to return only a single row, specifying `CommandBehavior.SingleRow` can improve your application performance.

Here is how you should use it.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
if (reader.HasRows)
{
while (reader.Read())
{
ct = new ctyp();
ct.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MyID"]);
ct.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
}
}
```

Comment: Better get rid of while (reader.Read()) and use if (reader.Read()) instead

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Jesús López in that using a micro ORM is the easiest approach. You can check out [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). Here's an example in your case...

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var record = connection.Query<ctyp>("SELECT MyID AS ID, Name FROM TABLE1 WHERE REC_ID = 1").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`record` will be of type `ctyp`, and it will be null if there was no record returned from DB.

Answer (score 0):

With EntityLite (a micro ORM I have developed) that is very easy, it has FirstOrDefault extension method that works on data readers:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var ct = reader.FirstOrDefault<ctyp>();
```

Here you have the signature of FirstOrDefault:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this System.Data.IDataReader reader)
    where T : new(), class
    Member of inercya.EntityLite.Extensions.DataReaderExtensions
```

Comment: After researching more on LINQ (after i saw FirstOrDefault in the post above) i saw that Linq to SQL or the EntityFramework could also be an alternative and could be used!?

Comment: Yes, It could be used, but you would need to redisign all your data access layer. However, using EntityLite you don't need to introduce any change. Just install EnitityLite.Core Nuget package and start using FirstOrDefault ToEnumerable and ToList on datareaders.

Comment: Thanks Jesus. I will have a look at EntityLite.